# How to make clear to manager how things have gone?

Tags: communication, teamwork, hierarchy

**EDIT: This is the second version of the question, question clarified**

I work in a company in a team, let's say A's team. There is also in the close group of workers, B, with whom I am working right now. And there is C, the manager of al A's team (including me), and B.

Note that C is the only one here with "hierarchy power" on us (assessment, payrises...). B is a tech worker, I am a tech worker, A is managing with no hierarhy power.

I worked with B for a long time. Everything was not fine, but that's another story. Then I continued alone and B went on other tasks.
BUT: B is an older worker than me, with more knowledge on the task: currently, B always asks me about how I am performing on the task. I think B's motives for such questions are 1/ technical interest in the task ("mine"), and 2/ lack of interest in current B's task (which I am not related to). The result however is that B looks like spending time on my task and not on B's task, while I don't (always) need B to come help me on my task.

A is aware of the situation, A has seen already B coming to me and saying:
B: "Hey, what's up on the task?"
"[Me answering]"
B: "Ok, next steps should be that and that, let's look together"
And I can't manage to put B out.

A told me about what he saw: "I know B is coming to work on your task, and not on his task. But I am not chief of B so I won't tell him to stop." I understand. I tried to tell B something along the lines: "Thanks for helping but don't feel forced to do so if you have other things to do".

So right now, the situation is:

- Me and B are working on my task
- B is not working on his task
- A is aware and have interests on both tasks, authority on my task

Problem is C, with hierarchic power, has reports from me by mail, and regular spoken reports from A and B. I don't think, since B is in the same meeting as A, that A raised the problem to C during their spoken reports. In my mail, I can't say neither that B intervened. I just say how tasks are going on.

So question is: I think I should convey the info about B's behaviour to C. I can ask C for a short meeting, but how could I convey, professionnally, the situation I described above?

Comment: "B is old tech: B always ask me about how I am continuing on the work. I think B's motive is interest in our-becoming-my task, and lack of interest in B's task." Sorry, I'm not at all clear what you mean by that - could you rephrase?

Comment: would the quick version of your problem be anything like "person from another team keeps doing my job along with me instead of his own, should I do something about it"?

Comment: Looks to me B`s interest may be in you and not in your task

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Does B annoy you, or are you worried that it looks like you need help? Team members should communicate about their work, and be aware of each other's changes.

Answer (score 1):

Person A is perceiving that you are having Person B work on your tasks more than their own.  That is an issue even if you're not the one asking for help because you're being perceived as someone who is giving out their assigned tasks.  This could reflect badly on you.

It could be that Person A is raising a concern to you directly before taking it to management.

You can bring up to your supervisor (Person C?) that Person B is overeagerly volunteering to help you on your tasks without you asking, and you're not comfortable turning him down.

If you're not sure you can ask Person A who to speak with in order to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Answering after your update. Also note that I'm doing a bit of assumptions in my examples feel free to correct me if I guessed wrong.

Does B disturb your work or impair your performances?

- Yes: Ask B to stop. If it does not work, discuss the situation with your manager and propose a solution like "I work best left alone. I'd like it best if B could stop trying to help me. I appreciate the thought but it disturbs me more than it helps."
- No: Don't say anything unless asked. It's not your problem. If B is under performing it's B's problem, not yours. If asked about B's behavior stay factual: "B regularly comes to my desk to ask about update on my task and provide advice on how to proceed next. B's advice help me progress faster on my task".

Since B is older and maybe more senior maybe it's one of it's hidden task to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Your question says "B" continues to work on your tasks even though he is now assigned to work on something else.  It also says that A encourages B to do this, by saying to him "Hey, what's up on the task?"

You did not say so explicitly, but I guess B irritates you when he does this.  I guess you want help from A and B in allowing you to do your task without interference.

You asked for advice about what to do.

First, do your best to put aside your personal irritation with B, and focus on the practical issues.  After all, this is business.

Second, set your goal. Decide what you want.  I guess, but you did not say, that you want the personal responsibility and authority to work on your task. I guess you want A to allow you to speak for your task rather than B.

Third, ask A for advice about how to deal with the problem. For it's his problem too. A technical manager succeeds when his team succeeds, but B has left A's team.  Say something to A like, "I thought you decided this was my task. I want to do the best job possible. How can I do it effectively and take responsibility for it if B comes around often and takes over?"  Then ask for his advice. That's not the same thing as asking him to do something about the problem.

It seems to me you should not go to C until you are sure A supports your goal. In fact, if A does support your goal, it should be his job (not yours) to go to C and ask for him to intervene with B.

If A doesn't support your goal, but rather wants B to stay involved in your task, maybe you should ask A to assign you a different task where you can have responsibility and authority.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It already gives hindsights, but with the first comment and your answer it looks like the question is not clear. I will edit and maybe you will change your answer according to the edit?